# using catch for a customized situation

Tags: c#

Is it possible to call catch for a special condition when you are inside of try without using system error? For instance if a value int value 1 and then I want to use "catch".

Comment: Do you mean throwing a custom exception?

Comment: Consider not raise exception if value = =1.

Comment: In C++ it was possible to catch any value, like say an int. However in any language that targets the CLR *(C#, VB.Net, etc..)*, All exceptions must derive from System.Exception. Might this be what you are asking???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in C# to *throw* an exception that doesn’t derive from `Exception`, even though the CLR allows it.

It *is* possible to catch such an exception, but it is not possible to access the object that was thrown:

```
try
{
    MethodThatThrows();
}
catch      // This catches everything, even objects not deriving from Exception
{
    // Process exception
}
```

As soon as you specify a variable (e.g. `catch (Exception e)`), C# requires that the type is `Exception` or derived from it.

Answer (score 2):

One of the biggest sins in programming:) Don't use exceptions for managing programming flow! Now to your question - the catch block can be called in case an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Your wording is a bit confusing but I think this is what you want.

```
int value = GetValue();
try
{
    if (value == 1)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    HappyPath(value);
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    SadPath(value);
}
```

Incidentally using exceptions for control flow is not the best practice.

Comment: You are almost correct. Just remove the "InvalidOperationException" part in try and catch and everyting would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

No. You should catch exceptions (you can filter them by type), and then inside `catch` block you can filter on any condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be saying that you want to catch an exception only in specific circumstances, and pass it through in all other circumstances? In that case, you can just use an `if` to check for the condition and then `throw` to re-throw the exception:

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // If it’s any value other than 1, we’re not interested in the exception
    if (value != 1)
        throw;        // note: throw; *not* throw e;

    // Process the exception here
}
```

Comment: I think you may be on to something here. *(No +1 until we get confirmation, I'm selfish like that...)*